# How to use apache wicket extensions?

Tags: java, import, wicket

I want to use the `AjaxFallbackDefaultDataTable` in wicket to view my data but these imports are showing error in eclipse :

```
import org.apache.wicket.extensions.ajax.markup.html.repeater.data.table.AjaxFallbackDefaultDataTable;   import org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.repeater.data.grid.ICellPopulator;
import org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.repeater.data.table.AbstractColumn;
import org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.repeater.data.table.IColumn;
import org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.repeater.data.table.PropertyColumn;
```

I guess I should be downloading an extensions jar file from somewhere but I don't know where at, and the Apache wicket website is vague regarding this point.

I am using eclipse with maven plugin and wicket 1.5RC1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the wicket-extensions library from the [maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.wicket/wicket-extensions).  This site shows assorted versions and allows you to retrieve it by just downloading the jar or by using various build tools including of course maven.

Maven is a good tool for dealing java dependency management, and [wicket quickstart](http://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html) is useful for starting wicket projects with a maven setup.

Answer (score 1):

I simply added the following lines to the pom.xml file to add the extensions dependency .

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicket-extensions</artifactId>
    <version>1.5-RC1</version>
</dependency>
```